# Lazy collection got fetched eagerly instead in jhipster app

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, jhipster

Ok, i've been recently investigating jhipster with a newly generated project. And while debugging the authentication process (token based) I've understood I don't clearly got the *@Transactional* principle and lazy association loading in entities. So jhipster generated such 2 entities, DAO and service layers:
**(original code, I didn't change anything)**

1. User

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "jhi_user")
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
   public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

       // omitted fields

       @JsonIgnore
       @ManyToMany
       @JoinTable(
           name = "jhi_user_authority",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
      @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
      private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>(); 

      // omitted setter & getters
   }
   ```
2. Authority

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "jhi_authority")
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
   public class Authority implements Serializable {

       @NotNull
       @Size(min = 0, max = 50)
       @Id
       @Column(length = 50)
       private String name;

      // omitted setter & getters
   }
   ```

   corresponding Dao layer

   ```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {                                              

        // omitted other CRUD methods

        Optional<User> findOneByLogin(String login);
   }
   ```

   and Service layer

   ```
   @Service
   @Transactional
   public class UserService {

       @Inject
       private UserRepository userRepository;

       @Transactional(readOnly = true)
       public User getUserWithAuthorities() {
           User user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentLogin()).get();
           user.getAuthorities().size(); // eagerly load the association
           return user;
       }

       // omitted other service methods
   }
   ```

When the Controller invokes service's **getUserWithAuthorities()** and the User is found it's has to be with un-initialised authorities field, so then

```
user.getAuthorities().size(); // eagerly load the association
```

could load them (Hibernate is a JPA provider used by jhipster here and it's defaulted to lazy collection association in entities). But in debugger I always see initialised authorities prior to **user.getAuthorities().size()** invocation.
I tried to remove the *@Transactional* from service method, but then *LazyInitializationException* occurs, that's why jhipster manual recommends ti use it in service layer. Also I tried to explicitly put *(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)* on authorities field of User.
I don't think that authorities got prefetched in a transaction somewhere else in service or dao layers(I got break points everywhere and **getUserWithAuthorities()** is the first method invoked). Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: are you sure the set is not used in a to string for logging or something, that could initialize the set as well, or a debug-watch on an expression that initializes it?

Comment: Though I used no debug-watches and only hibernate sql logging, you are partially right. When in debugger I expanded the **User** instance the query to get authorities executed (as per sql log). Strange enough as **toString()** for **User** doesn't use authorities field at all.